# Usability of COB LED filaments as replacement for traditional filaments

Tags: led, automotive, light, cob

COB LED filament household lightbulbs are a thing now. Can someone explain to me what limitations there are to using these COB filaments in car headlights? They emit a very similar light pattern if you preserve the geometry and glass shape. I believe there must be a reason why manufacturers kept clear of this approach for the past 10 years.

[image: LED COB filament in a H7 bulb]

Comment: Do they emit in all angles consistently?

Comment: @Andyaka you raised a good point, thank you. I'd think it's possible with 4+ filaments (as they do in household bulbs). but still not as good as the original tungsten filament

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A car headlight requires about 1000-3000 lumens.

With LED lumen efficacy in the 100-200 lm/W, this means 10-30W electrical power.

This means 7-20W dissipation in the LED that must be evacuated to outside air.

An object the size of a headlamp filament needs to be at extremely high temperatures to be able to transfer this amount of heat through the gas in the bulb envelope.

The filament is about the same size as a 1/4W resistor, and the resistor will usually reach this dissipation around 125°C which is too high for LEDs.

LEDs are limited to low temperatures, and best used under 80°C, so there is absolutely no way to have a LED this powerful in free air. It has to be on a rather chunky heat sink.

This is why all LED retrofit bulbs look like [this](https://www.france-xenon.com/fr/gamme-complete-philips/72010-ampoules-bi-led-homologue-h4-pro6001-ultinon-philips-11342u6001x2-5800k-230-8719018016560.html?gad_source=1):

[image]

The alternative is to have a headlight that does not use a bulb, in this case the LEDs, heatsink and optics can be designed as a whole.

Comment: I was suspecting the same reason, thank you, I am accepting this answer. Do you (or anyone else) think that arranging some sort of COB LED(s) in a cylindrical shape (instead of the flat plane as in your picture) could result in such similarity to old filament type bulbs that they could be used in old cars, without needing to worry about light scatter (blinding oncoming traffic)? Having the heatsink inside the cylinder?

Comment: The cylinder would have to be very thin, not good for heat transfer

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons I can think of:
Cost of tooling
Voltage difference.

I'll comment on the last one, you couldn't just repurpose a COB filament from a house light (120V) to a car headlight (12V), because you'd need to change the configuration from something that's in series to something thats more in parallel.

Most of the lights already use COB but not in a filament, they put them on a PCB, which is easier to manufacture for most people. It must make economical sense to not switch to a filament.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons; in addition to Voltage Spike’s answer the form factor is far from ideal for a LED since there’s no effective heat sinking and so the LED will run very hot (which is predictable because a tungsten filament only glows when it’s very hot).  Also vehicle makers already have a well-established solution that works reasonably well, so why change to a less proven technology that offers little in return, since a saving of a few watts means little in the context of a motor car that’s burning a few kW even when at idle.

Answer (score 0):

**Etendue**

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue

COB LED filament household lightbulbs produce a lot of light by having a large surface area - which is similar how a lot of light is produced by a fluorescent lamp in a tube format.

A headlamp wants to be able to focus the available light into a narrow forward beam - which by etendue requires a small emitting area (for the same optical power output).

Small sources of intense light are commonly produced by small tungsten filaments or by small arc lamps. This is difficult in an LED format as the white light is produced by exciting a phosphor with blue LED light - and limited by the optical power density and temperature the phosphor can tolerate and by the heat dissipation of the lamp. A tungsten lamp (by definition an incandescent source) wants to run hot.